# open a model window by jquery onchange of select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

How can I open a model window by jquery onchange of select option???

Code for Modal window is here:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" id="myModal" style="display:none" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
       Some Contents here..         
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code for Select option is here:

```
<select id="selectbox">
    <option value="0">- Select -</option>
    <option value="1">yes</option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to grab the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default) and put it in your [`(document).ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler.

```
$('#dialog-modal').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false
});
```

After that, you define a function that says on [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) it should open the dialog:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');
});
```

To say that it should open on **'yes'**, just put an if statement representing your **'yes'** choice:

```
if ($(this).val() == "1") {
//...code...
}
```

## DEMO

Answer (score 4):

Use Jquery UI and .change.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#selectbox").change(function(){

   $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;


});
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CBKQcuHKH8uMXQVkySC8?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

USe the `change()` event of select,

```
$("#selectbox").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
        var options = {
            "backdrop": "static"
        }
        $("#myModal").modal(options);
    }
});
```

Comment: here backdrop and static is what?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$("#selectbox").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
        $('#myModal).modal('show');
      }
 })
```