# How to open model window on option selection?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Select tag and modal window tag ..

```
<select id="selectBox">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
</select>
<div id="dialog-modal">test</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#dialogmodal').dialog({  
                 modal:true,
                 autoOpen:false
 });
          $('select').change(function(){
              $('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectBox">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
</select>
<div id="dialog-modal">test</div>
```

Comment: Duplicate question [Open-a-model-window-by-jquery-onchange-of-select-option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24032802/2324206)

Comment: Your script is already working check : https://jsfiddle.net/Lnxbosz4/

Comment: no i have tried in on my page..........its not working

Comment: which browser and version of jquery?

Comment: do you have any console error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you've written `#dialogmodal` when you meant to write `#dialog-modal` on the second line of your JS code.